# How do I automatically add threads to a pool based on the computational needs of the program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

We have a C++ program which, depending on the way the user configures it, may be CPU bound or IO bound. For the purpose of loose coupling with the program configuration, I'd like to have my thread pool automatically realize when the program would benefit from more threads (i.e. CPU bound). It would be nice if it realized when it was I/O bound and reduced the number of workers, but that would just be a bonus (i.e. I'd be happy with something that just automatically grows without automatic shrinkage).

We use Boost so if there's something there that would help we can use it. I realize that any solution would probably be platform specific, so we're mainly interested in Windows and Linux, with a tertiary interest in OS X or any other *nix.

Comment: At the point where you find yourself creating a large number of threads in order to hide IO latency, it's time to look into thread pools with IOCP (or epoll, depending on OS).

Comment: Note that boost::asio provides an abstraction layer for those things

Comment: It's the opposite. Our files are big enough that a single thread can saturate the IO if we're not doing any intensive processing as we read. As the processing gets more complicated, things can become CPU bound and then it benefits from another thread (or more). In practice we have a signal processing algorithm that really needs the extra threads, but when it's not used, the extra threads actually cost us time because they cause the file to (sometimes) be accessed out of order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: use distinct fixed-size thread pools for CPU intensive operations and for IOs. In addition to the pool sizes, further regulation of the number of active threads will be done by the bounded-buffer (Producer/Consumer) that synchronizes the computer and IO steps of your workflow.

For compute- and data-intensive problems where the bottlenecks are a moving target between different resources (e.g. CPU vs IO), it can be useful to make a clear distinction between a thread and a thread, particularly, as a first approximation:

- A thread that is created to use more CPU cycles ("CPU thread")
- A thread that is created to handle an asynchronous IO operation ("IO thread")

More generally, threads should be segregated by the type of resources that they need. The aim should be to ensure that a single thread doesn't use more than one resource (e.g. avoiding switching between reading data and processing data in the same thread). When a tread uses more than one resource, it should be split and the two resulting threads should be synchronized through a bounded-buffer.

Typically there should be exactly as many CPU threads as needed to saturate the instruction pipelines of all the cores available on the system. To ensure that, simply have a "CPU thread pool" with exactly that many threads that are dedicated to computational work only. That would be `boost::` or `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` if that can be trusted. When the application needs less, there will simply be unused threads in the CPU thread pool. When it needs more, the work is queued. Instead of a "CPU thread pool", you could use c++11 `std::async` but you would need to implement a thread throttling mechanism with your selection of synchronization tools (e.g. a counting semaphore).

In addition to the "CPU thread pool", there can be another thread pool (or several other thread pools) dedicated to asynchronous IO operations. In your case, it seems that IO resource contention is potentially a concern. If that's the case (e.g. a local hard drive) the maximum number of threads should be carefully controlled (e.g. at most 2 read and 2 write threads on a local hard drive). This is conceptually the same as with CPU threads and you should have one fixed size thread pool for reading and another one for writing. Unfortunately, there will probably not be any good primitive available to decide on the size of these thread pools (measuring might be simple though, if your IO patterns are very regular). If resource contention is not an issue (e.g. NAS or small HTTP requests) then  `boost::asio` or c++11 `std::async` would probably be a better option than a thread pool; in which case, thread throttling can be entirely left to the bounded-buffers.

Comment: Hi Come, thanks for the answer. I'm not sure how to apply your answer, but that may be because I didn't explain my use case clearly enough. The problem with a fixed-size thread pool for me is that I have a fixed number of tasks (thousands) that are going to get queued, and the job of the pool is to do them as fast as possible. When the options are such that the threads will be I/O bound, it's better if I just have 1 or 2 threads, because otherwise the tasks will get out of order on the disk, which increases seeking and buffering costs. If they're CPU bound, I benefit from more threads.

Comment: So I was thinking of something more along the lines of my task dispatcher class starting with one thread, then monitoring the CPU usage of my process relative to the CPU usage of the system (divided by the number of physical cores). When the dispatcher detects that my process is using nearly the entire core, it will add another thread. If it starts using two entire cores, it adds another thread. And so on.

Comment: @MattChambers for simplicity I'll assume you have 8 cores and that optimal read is on a 2 threads. Create a "CPU thread pool" with 8 threads and a "read thread pool" with 2 threads, with a bounded buffer in between. If IO is the bottleneck, both read threads will be fully used, the bounded buffer will stay mostly empty and some of the CPU threads will be idle. If CPU is the bottleneck, all CPU threads will be fully used, the bounded buffer will stay mostly full and the read threads will be partly idle. It is self regulating and always optimizes around the bottleneck.

Comment: @MattChambers Regarding the statement that you have thousands of tasks that are going to get queued, that's not an issue: each CPU thread will process many tasks. If you were posting a specific minimal use case it would be easier to provide effective solutions.

Comment: OK now I get it: your comment is a concise explanation of the interaction between the CPU and IO threads. In my current solution, the worker threads are doing both the IO and the CPU work. You would modify this so that there are two sets of workers, in a producer/consumer relationship (except the CPU threads are also producers: for the main thread). It's more complex than my idea but it ensures that there are a limited number of threads doing IO, which could be part of my performance problem (it's hard to tease out whether out-of-order IO is the problem or too many IO threads is the problem).